# Android how to place a button in correct place on a back ground image to support all screen sizes

Tags: android

I've a button on top of a back ground image in Relative Layout. The image itself contains the 'Register' button shaped image , So now I've placed a android button on the portion where exactly the Text "Register" is there .  But my android button is going in different positions based on screens size. Please suggest me how do I place the android button on the required portion of

Comment: can you post the xml layout?

Answer (score 0):

Put that button to a new relative layout under the your relative layout. And add

```
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
```

property to new relative layout. So now button always be at the center.

EDIT:

Use this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/home1"
 >


<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
     android:layout_width="195dp" 
     android:layout_height="95dp" 
     android:layout_marginBottom="194dp" 
     android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
     android:text="button_play" />


 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:background="@drawable/home1">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="195dp"
        android:layout_height="95dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="194dp"
        android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>

Comment: Here is my XML...actually I couldn't add any image it's asking some points. Hope you understood my problem. on an image I'm placing the button to fit in correct place.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean to say the image itself contains text "Register"?

There's no easy way you can do it that way in Android.

Problem is Android has different screen sizes and screen densities. So your image itself will start looking blurred and the text in the image may get pixelated making it look ugly on some devices.

So what's the right way then? Use a simple background and place your button and text using `ImageButton` and `TextView` or just `Button` with proper background to it.

Comment: Thank you for the answerer. But I've have four images with 8 buttons . The images are very nice and we wanted not to touch the images so keeping the external buttons on top of them. Please suggest

Comment: The images are nice only on that device you are checking on. Try using the same image on a different device with different resolution and you will see a lot of issues.

Answer (score 0):

Developing for Android is not pixel-perfect as it is/can be for iOS, so this kind of task is kinda tricky. You basically shouldn't have one piece of a button (text in this case) divided from another (button's container).

But if you don't have a choice, I would suggest you to:

1. Open some photo-editor and get actual positions of your "Register" text on the background image. You will get four X,Y positions for left bottom, left top, right top, right bottom.
2. Get height and width of your background (or JUST height and width of the device if the background covers all space - `match_parent`).
3. You will then have to measure the ratio, so you will know where those points are on a display.
4. Add a button at "Register" text location.

EDITED

4. Actually instead of adding a button you can just add a click listener to your background image and intercept user's clicks. If a click was inside of a boundaries (our rectangle shape of XY points) then re-direct user/do something.

Sounds like a lot of work but as I think about it, this is the only way to be absolutely sure you will have a button at exact place you want.

Good luck!